# HTML code throwing a blank space issue in the middle of notification

Tags: html, zendesk

I'm creating a html branded signature for use in a Zendesk trigger email notification.

The code I've created looks correct and renders properly with a HTML code viewer such as codepen. However when I input the code into the trigger and then create a ticket. When I view the email notification on the ticket, there's a large blank space showing in the middle of my code between the telephone number and the social icons.

I've tried removing the table and putting in the icons in divs only but this makes the icons show up in the email notification in 1 column when I want them to appear as 1 row.

```html
<div>
  <div dir="ltr"><span style="color: #4f4f4f;"><br /></span><a href="https://genoapay.com"><img src="https://www.genoapay.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/12/genoapay-logo-for-emails.png" alt="Genoapay.com" /></a>
  </div>
  <div dir="ltr"><span style="color: #1155cc;"><u><br /></u></span><a href="https://www.genoapay.com">genoapay.com</a></div>
  <div dir="ltr"><a href="tel:0800436625">0800 436 625</div>
<br>
<table>
  <tr>
      <td><a href="https://www.facebook.com/genoapay/"><img src="https://a8b03ffbc00ed4da54a1-0c6684360696717b63d89dbc0edb802c.ssl.cf1.rackcdn.com/icon-facebook_28x28.jpg" alt="Genoapay on Facebook" /></a></td>
    <td><a href="https://twitter.com/genoapay"><img src="https://a8b03ffbc00ed4da54a1-0c6684360696717b63d89dbc0edb802c.ssl.cf1.rackcdn.com/icon-twitter_28x28.jpg" alt="Genoapay on Twitter" /></a></td>
    <td><a href="https://www.linkedin.com/company/12898566/"><img src="https://a8b03ffbc00ed4da54a1-0c6684360696717b63d89dbc0edb802c.ssl.cf1.rackcdn.com/icon-linkedin_28x28.jpg" alt="Genoapay on LinkedIn" /></a></td>
    <td><a href="https://www.instagram.com/genoapaynz/"><img src="https://a8b03ffbc00ed4da54a1-0c6684360696717b63d89dbc0edb802c.ssl.cf1.rackcdn.com/icon-instagram_28x28.png" alt="Genoapay on Instagram" /></a></td>
    <td><a href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCVRNdqLBWyIZXkB6x2LCvcA/"><img src="https://a8b03ffbc00ed4da54a1-0c6684360696717b63d89dbc0edb802c.ssl.cf1.rackcdn.com/icon-youtube_28x28.png" alt="Genoapay on YouTube" /></a></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

*This is how it should look*:

[image: this is how it should look]

*This is how it's rendering in the email notification from a Zendesk ticket*:

[image: this is how it's rendering in the email notification from a Zendesk ticket]

Answer (score 0):

You have `<br>` tag instead of closing `</div>` (first div with telephone number).

Answer (score 0):

Try below HTML

```
<div dir="ltr">
    <a href="https://genoapay.com">
        <img src="https://www.genoapay.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/12/genoapay-logo-for-emails.png" alt="Genoapay.com" />
    </a>
</div>
<br/>
<div dir="ltr"><a href="https://www.genoapay.com">genoapay.com</a></div>
<div dir="ltr"><a href="tel:0800436625">0800 436 625</div>
<br/>
<table style="margin:0;">
  <tr>
  <td><a href="https://www.facebook.com/genoapay/"><img src="https://a8b03ffbc00ed4da54a1-0c6684360696717b63d89dbc0edb802c.ssl.cf1.rackcdn.com/icon-facebook_28x28.jpg" alt="Genoapay on Facebook" /></a></td>
  <td><a href="https://twitter.com/genoapay"><img src="https://a8b03ffbc00ed4da54a1-0c6684360696717b63d89dbc0edb802c.ssl.cf1.rackcdn.com/icon-twitter_28x28.jpg" alt="Genoapay on Twitter" /></a></td>
  <td><a href="https://www.linkedin.com/company/12898566/"><img src="https://a8b03ffbc00ed4da54a1-0c6684360696717b63d89dbc0edb802c.ssl.cf1.rackcdn.com/icon-linkedin_28x28.jpg" alt="Genoapay on LinkedIn" /></a></td>
  <td><a href="https://www.instagram.com/genoapaynz/"><img src="https://a8b03ffbc00ed4da54a1-0c6684360696717b63d89dbc0edb802c.ssl.cf1.rackcdn.com/icon-instagram_28x28.png" alt="Genoapay on Instagram" /></a></td>
  <td><a href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCVRNdqLBWyIZXkB6x2LCvcA/"><img src="https://a8b03ffbc00ed4da54a1-0c6684360696717b63d89dbc0edb802c.ssl.cf1.rackcdn.com/icon-youtube_28x28.png" alt="Genoapay on YouTube" /></a></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

And if you want to use DIV for icon then use as blow with style

```
<div style="display:inline-block; margin-right:3px;"><a href="https://www.facebook.com/genoapay/"><img src="https://a8b03ffbc00ed4da54a1-0c6684360696717b63d89dbc0edb802c.ssl.cf1.rackcdn.com/icon-facebook_28x28.jpg" alt="Genoapay on Facebook" /></a><div>
```